# Como llamar una imagen desde C#, almacenada en SQL Server. Usando Stored Procedure y Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, entity-framework

Tengo este código hecho hasta ahora donde aplico el SP "InsertarEmpleado", el mismo agrega registros a la BD:

```
var Insertar_NuevoEmpleado = _empleados.InsertarEmpleado(txtcedula.Text, txtnombres.Text, txtapellidos.Text, txtcargo.Text, txtdepartamento.Text, Convert.ToDecimal(txtsalario.Text), txtUrl.Text);
```

Lo que intento hacer es una búsqueda con otro SP donde me traiga los registros correspondientes al parámetro enviado. Sucede que, el formulario posee un PictureBox, por el medio del cual se almacena una imagen a la base de datos(*propiamente se almacena la ruta donde se encuentra la imagen*) y este es el código de búsqueda:

```
 private void btnBuscarEmpleado_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnBuscarEmpleado.Image = imageList1.Images[0];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBuscarCedula.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ingrese un número de cédula valido", "Buscar Empleado", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            return;
        }

        empresaEntities _empleados = new empresaEntities();
        {
            nomina _trabajador = new nomina();

            var BuscarEmpleado = _empleados.BuscarEmpleados(txtBuscarCedula.Text).ToList();

            if (BuscarEmpleado.Count() > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("El empleado existe en la base de datos.", "¡ATENCIÓN!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);

                txtcedula.Text = BuscarEmpleado.FirstOrDefault().cedula.ToString("N0");
                txtnombres.Text = BuscarEmpleado.FirstOrDefault().nombres;
                txtapellidos.Text = BuscarEmpleado.FirstOrDefault().apellidos;
                txtcargo.Text = BuscarEmpleado.FirstOrDefault().cargo;
                txtdepartamento.Text = BuscarEmpleado.FirstOrDefault().departamento;
                txtsalario.Text = BuscarEmpleado.FirstOrDefault().salario.ToString("N2");
                txtUrl.Text = BuscarEmpleado.FirstOrDefault().UrlFoto;
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(BuscarImagen.FileName); **<- AQUI me marca el ERROR**
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("El número de cédula no existe en la base de datos. ¿Desea ingresar uno nuevo?", "Confirmar", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }

        }
    }
```

**Se evidencia que el pictureBox no tiene código alguno.**
La pregunta es, como hago el llamado correspondiente para este objeto, donde el mismo me muestre la imagen a la que esta asociado el parámetro enviado mediante el SP.

Les comento:

El SP me funciona evidentemente sin el parámetro de Imagen, pero la idea es traer los registros y a su vez que la imagen se muestre también.

**Para mas info:**

Busco la imagen mediante el siguiente código y almaceno la ruta de la imagen:

```
 private void btnBuscarFoto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog BuscarImagen = new OpenFileDialog();
        BuscarImagen.Filter = "Archivo PNG|*.png";

        if (BuscarImagen.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(BuscarImagen.FileName);
        }
            txtUrl.Text = BuscarImagen.FileName;
    }
```

Adicional a esto, cuando hago el Debugg de la aplicación, me marca error en esta linea cuando intenta hacer la búsqueda.

```
 pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(BuscarImagen.FileName);
```

Indicando lo siguiente: **Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  CS1061 'List' does not contain a definition for 'FileName' and no extension method 'FileName' accepting a first argument of type 'List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Si tienen opiniones o respuestas al respecto, ejemplos en EF.

Gracias!

Comment: Se almacena la ruta o la imagen?

Comment: y entonces? al picturebox le pasas la ruta.. o eso no funciona? ojo que la ruta tiene que ser completa.

Comment: Pero, en tu segundo ejemplo estas haciendo exactamente eso, le pasas una ruta y supongo que aparece en el PB... lo probaste de esa forma?

Comment: Borremos los comentarios. agrega todo eso a la pregunta. El problema es que en tu EF no se como se llama el campo que tiene el nombre del archivo a buscar. Obviamente no se llama FileName. como se llama?

Comment: esa es la ruta que sigue para buscar la imagen: C:\Temp\fotoempleados. que se almacena en: (txtUrl.Text = BuscarImagen.FileName;) Es a lo que te refieres con: "El problema es que en tu EF no se como se llama el campo que tiene el nombre del archivo a buscar. Obviamente no se llama FileName. como se llama?"

Comment: no hombre.. en tu DB, estas guardando una ruta (segun lo que dijiste). esa ruta, es un varchar y en tu POCO deberia estar viniendo en algun campo. ahora como haces con el resto de los campos, deberias pasarla al PB con un loadimage de la misma forma que haces en el ejemplo que pasaste. Tu ruta a la imagen es BuscarEmpleado.FirstOrDefault().UrlFoto???

Comment: si, la ruta que se almacena en el campo UrlFoto de la DB es esta: C:\Temp\fotoempleados\3ned.png. y en el winform tengo un textBox que me almacena la misma cuando escoge la imagen la primera vez. Cuando intento hacer lo del PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile() que tengo en el código siguiente, no me funciona...

Comment: mejor.. que error tira?

Comment: Cuando voy a hacer la búsqueda me envia a esta parte que es el Contex.cs:public virtual ObjectResult<BuscarEmpleados_Result> BuscarEmpleados(string cedula){var cedulaParameter = cedula != null ?
new ObjectParameter("cedula", cedula) :new ObjectParameter("cedula", typeof(string));return((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<BuscarEmpleados_Result>("BuscarEmpleados",cedulaParameter);} y me dice ERROR:Additionalinformation:Elparámetro detipo'Productos.BuscarEmpleados_Result'enExecuteFunctionesincompatibleconeltipo'empresaModel.BuscarEmpleados_Result' devuelto por la función.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He resuelto el error que he escrito en el ultimo comentario.

Tuve que eliminar el modelo y volverlo a cargar, para que me tomase los cambios que había hecho. Así que de esa manera me ha funcionado la aplicación, trayéndome la imagen y los datos asociados a ella. Dejo el código del botón "búsqueda" para todos aquellos que necesiten una idea similar a la mía:

```
 private void btnBuscarEmpleado_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnBuscarEmpleado.Image = imageList1.Images[0];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBuscarCedula.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ingrese un número de cédula valido", "Buscar Empleado", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            return;
        }

       using(empresaEntities1 _empleados = new empresaEntities1())
        {
            nomina _trabajador = new nomina();

            var BuscarEmpleado = _empleados.BuscarEmpleados(txtBuscarCedula.Text).ToList();

            if (BuscarEmpleado.Count() > 0)
            {
                OpenFileDialog BuscarImagen = new OpenFileDialog();

                MessageBox.Show("El empleado existe en la base de datos.", "¡ATENCIÓN!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);

                txtcedula.Text = BuscarEmpleado.FirstOrDefault().cedula;
                txtnombres.Text = BuscarEmpleado.FirstOrDefault().nombres;
                txtapellidos.Text = BuscarEmpleado.FirstOrDefault().apellidos;
                txtcargo.Text = BuscarEmpleado.FirstOrDefault().cargo;
                txtdepartamento.Text = BuscarEmpleado.FirstOrDefault().departamento;
                txtsalario.Text = BuscarEmpleado.FirstOrDefault().salario.ToString("N2");
                txtUrl.Text = BuscarEmpleado.FirstOrDefault().UrlFoto;
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(txtUrl.Text);
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("El número de cédula no existe en la base de datos. ¿Desea ingresar uno nuevo?", "Confirmar", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }

        }
    }
```

***Tomen en cuenta que este código esta diseñado con Entity Framework.***

Answer (score 1):

Este es un ejemplo para obtener imágenes almacenadas en SQLServer:

```
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("select imgfile from myimages where imgname=@param", connection);
    SqlParameter myparam = command1.Parameters.Add("@param", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30);
    myparam.Value = txtimgname.Text;
    byte[] img = (byte[])command1.ExecuteScalar();
    MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream();
    str.Write(img, 0, img.Length);
    Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(str);
    connection.Close();
```

Comment: Cool! Le sera de ayuda para aquellos que usen SQLcommand. En mi caso uso EF.